# Server side button click does not fire when I use it in RadAjaxManager

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, telerik, radajaxmanager

I am using several settings in RadAjaxManager. I have a server control asp button which re-loads the whole page when clicked. To revent that I put this setting in RadAjaxManager

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnPrint">
    <UpdatedControls>
        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btnPrint" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxPanel"/>
    </UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

but for some reason my code behind click event does not fire. Any ideas please

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel"  PostBackControls="btnPrint" runat="server">
     <div class="grid-wrapper" id="subcodeDiv" style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0px; width: 1160px; float: left; overflow: hidden">
         <table class="subcodesdata">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" ></asp:Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: in your `telerik:RadAjaxPanel` did you set the `PostBackControls="btnPrint"`

Comment: Yes I tried that. Please see my updated question. Unfortunately still does not work

Comment: Try referencing the `AjaxPanel` instead of just the button, in the `AjaxSetting `. With : `<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxPanel">` and  `<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1" />`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. May I ask for a little [MCVE]? Because the 8 magic balls we use as debuging tool is actually unavaidable. as someone is  already debugging his code with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you applied both `RadAjaxManager` and `RadAjaxPanel` to the same button, which is wrong and unnecessary. You just need to pick one of those methods here.

Please try the following working code samples. When you click the Print button 1, the text will be loaded into the `span` tag and displayed on the screen without the page being refreshed. It works the same for Print button 2 as well.

**RadAjaxPanel** method

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="rap" PostBackControls="btnPrint2">
            <div class="grid-wrapper">
            <table class="subcodesdata">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint2" runat="server" Text="Print 2" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnPrint2_Click"></asp:Button>
                        <br />
                        <span runat="server" id="span2"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

    protected void btnPrint2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        span2.InnerHtml = "Print button 2 clicked...";
    }
```

**RadAjaxManager** method

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ram" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnPrint1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="subcodeDiv" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<div class="grid-wrapper" id="subcodeDiv" runat="server">
        <table class="subcodesdata">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPrint1" runat="server" Text="Print 1" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnPrint1_Click"></asp:Button>
                    <br />
                    <span runat="server" id="span1"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    protected void btnPrint1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        span1.InnerHtml = "Print button 1 clicked...";
    }
```

Comment: I tried both. First method (RadAjaxPanel) stops the trigger of the event and second method (RadAjaxManager) has the refresh problem.

Comment: @user2837961 I noticed that there was a typo in the 2nd method where the `AjaxControlID` was given a wrong value. I have updated it with the correct control ID now so please try it again and it shouldn't give you the refresh problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread here it goes the solution if someone else is still struggling with it. The problem here is that you cannot have a button updating itself. Well, you CAN but then your page won't work as expected. Instead the button should update secondary controls. When you make your button to update itself every time you click it will just reset itself and therefore will never fire the server side function.

So this is the correct way of doing it:

```html
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ajaxmanager1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnPrint">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="subcodeDiv" />
           </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

HOWEVER, I am not sure that Telerik controls will update a **div**. I know that they will work fine with controls but not divs.

Even so I think that the button shouldn't be inside the div you are trying to update.

Anyway, if the example above does NOT work try the following one below. It will for sure work -- notice that I replaced the div by a label control:

```html
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
 
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ajaxmanager1" runat="server" EnableAJAX="true">
 <AjaxSettings>
  <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnPrint">
   <UpdatedControls>
    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="label1" />
   </UpdatedControls>
  </telerik:AjaxSetting>
 </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" ></asp:Button>
<asp:label autopostback="true" id="label1" runat="server" visible="true"></asp:label>
```